# Convergence radius of non-standard series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

The convergence radius $R$ of a series $\sum a_kx^k$ can be calculated using

$\frac{1}{R}=\lim_{k\to \infty} |\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_{k}}|$  or $\frac{1}{R}=\lim_{k\to \infty} \sqrt[k]{|a|}$.

What modifications are required in order for these formulas to work when the starting index $k \neq 0$ or when the exponent of $x$ is not $k$, ie. in cases such as

$\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{2}{k+1}z^{k}$ or $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{k(k+1)}{2}z^{2k}$   ?

I'm thinking that f $|z|< \frac{1}{\lim_{k\to \infty} |\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_{k}}|}$, then we should be able to write $|z^2|< \frac{1}{\lim_{k\to \infty} |\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_{k}}|}$ (if the exponent of $x$ is $2k$), and then take the square root of both sides of the equation to find the x for which the equation converges?

As for the indexation, it should not matter, as indexation apparently does not determine convergence/divergence.

Comment: Those new series are same as the original one with some coefficients $0$. So the same formulas work.

Comment: The formulas do not work directly as $a_{2k-1}=0$ and the limits do not exist. I suggest you apply the formulas to numerical series i.e. you determine when $\sum {k(k+1)\over 2}z^{2k}$ is convergent which gives the limit $\lim_k\sqrt[k]{|a_k|}|z|^2=|z|^2<1.$ A similar problem occurs when you are considering for example the series $\sum 3^kz^{2^k}$